# How to run deja-dup in gtk and debug mode?

Tags: 12.04, server, deja-dup

As in the title I'm looking for a way to start deja-dup in gtk mode also in debugging mode. Excuse me if there was a question like this, but after an hour of research i could find a single one. Using Ubuntu Server 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 before running.

I'm not sure what you mean by GTK mode.  Deja Dup is always in GTK mode.  Do you mean how to run it manually from the command line?  If so, try this:

DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1 deja-dup --backup